# Amazon Athena "ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION returns wrong number of records

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I run this command in Amazon Athena:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD PARTITION (dt='2018-03-01')
location 's3://my_data/my_folder/
```

Then I count the results:

```
SELECT count(1) from table_name;
```

However, it returns the wrong number of records.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to **drill-down to the data** to figure out why this is happening. It might be because there is some data with bad characters, or it might be importing header rows.

Try and find some **data that is missing** (I'm presuming the count is less than you expect?), then look at the data in the source file to figure out why it didn't load correctly.

Once you find the load that didn't load, you could even put it into a **separate file** and try some queries against it to narrow-down the cause.